# KAFKA Broker bind external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have the Kafka docker image from : https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/
and I am setting it up on the google cloud. I have an external IP and I have opened the ports I am using for the broker, but the broker cannot attach to the google external IP as that is how google works, but when I try to attach to 0.0.0.0 it also not possible as explained on this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4116

I have tried to attach to the internal IP but then it is not reachable from outside. Do I have to create a forwarding rule? I had no issue setting kafka up on other cloud providers. With the same configuration It worked so it seems to really be a network specific issue.

Comment: Have you opened the needed ports in the firewall rules for your project's VPC network firewall rules (not the local machine firewall?).  The Google external IPs aren't visible on the VMs themself, that is handled by Google's network automatically.  Binding to the internal IP should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes the ports are open, I tested creating a webapp listening on that port and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind it to the 0.0.0.0 IP because it is not routable, since zookeeper will take this IP to identify the broker. There are some discussion here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4116

This tutorial exaplins how to do it for AWS: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

You have to define multiple listeners and advertised listeners:

> **Option 2 - external address is NOT resolvable locally**
>
> You will need to configure two listeners for Kafka:
>
> **1- Communication within the AWS network (VPC).** This could be inter-broker communication
>   (i.e. between brokers), and between other components running in the
>   VPC such as Kafka Connect, or third-party clients or producers. For
>   these comms, we need to use the internal IP of the EC2 machine (or
>   hostname, if DNS is configured).
>
> **2- External AWS traffic.** This could be testing connectivity from a
>   laptop, or simply from machines not hosted in Amazon. In both cases,
>   the external IP of the instance needs to be used (or hostname, if DNS
>   is configured).

Example:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://ip-172-31-18-160.us-west-2.compute.internal:19092,EXTERNAL://ec2-54-191-84-122.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```